# Stop auto-updating on RLMResults

Tags: realm

i want to replace all existings objects in a realm by one new record:

```
 let realm = RLMRealm(path: ...)
 let newRecord = MyRealm() 
 //... fill record
 let existingJustNow = MyRealm.allObjectsInRealm(realm)        

 realm.beginWriteTransaction()
 realm.addObject(newRecord)  // first write new record
 realm.commitWriteTransaction()
 realm.beginWriteTransaction()
 realm.deleteObjects(existingJustNow) // now delete the older ones
 realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

but this will delete all objects (even the new one).

Is there a way to stop the auto-update of the allObjects method?
Or have i to copy the results in an array and delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you'd be best to copy the RLMObjects into an array to delete them afterwards.

```
let realm = RLMRealm(path: ...)
let newRecord = MyRealm() 
//... fill record
let existingJustNow = MyRealm.allObjectsInRealm(realm).valueForKey("self") as! [MyRealm]

realm.beginWriteTransaction()
realm.addObject(newRecord)  // first write new record
realm.deleteObjects(existingJustNow) // now delete the older ones
realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

The good news is that making an array of RLMObjects doesn't have to copy all their contents from the database into memory, they're still lazily-loaded accessors, so it's pretty lightweight.